# React | Unit testing how to test methods inside the succesful AJAX call?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

Currently, In my react app, I have an ajax call method that has `setState` if the ajax call is successful, I already mocked the api response, it seems that the method won't execute anything else other than returning the response

For example,

```js
// This is the ajax method
getProductData(productId) {
   // I already successfully mocked the response
   getProductById(productId).then(productResponse => {
   // I am trying make sure that the state is being updated with response data
   this.setState({
     product: productResponse.data
   })
});
}
```

This is my test

```js
test('Make sure my state is being updated with response data', async () => {
  const component = shallow(
      <MyComponent />
  );
  
  component.instance().getProductData(1);
  // This is where my test failed, as it's not updating anything
  expect(component.state().product).to.equal('SOMETHING');
});
```

Tried using `setTimeout` to asynchronously test the method, suggested by Jonah Pereira

```js
test('Make sure my state is being updated with response data', async () => {
  const component = shallow(
      <MyComponent />
  );
  
  component.instance().getProductData(1);
  // Using settimeout still not solving the problem, 
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(component.state().product).to.equal('SOMETHING');
    
    // Not even this, that means the test totally ignored the setTimeout
    expect('abc').to.equal('cba');
  }, 0)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I test my react components which involve AJAX calls i enclose my methods inside a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(() => 
{
    expect(component.state().product).to.equal('SOMETHING');
}, 0);
```

Comment: is it really working ? I tried using `setTimeout`, and it looks like my test just completely ignored it.